# GET /content/test/***********.html HTTP/1.1]org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html

Tags: java, servlets, aem, sling

I am  seeing  below error for many of the content pages in logs.

Enable JSON and Enable XML are selected for  DefaultGetServlet and I am using AEM 6.5 version.

```
GET /content/test/***********.html HTTP/1.1]org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/content/******/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/*****_copy.
```

While debugging I have observed that nodes are not having `sling:resourceType`. We have the same issue for "n" of nodes in our project. How can we delete these nodes using servlet?

*For example*: How can I delete text node which does not have `sling:resourceType`.

```
/content
  /company
    /us/en
      /test
        /text
```

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]. And provide a little bit more information

Comment: That has to do with a component not with the page, look if one of the components included is missing or using a wrong sling:resourceType

Comment: That happens when a bundle is not installed, check all your bundles to detect what's not working correctly, then fix the dependencies.